# xhr status 0 ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un script donde uso ajax que no entra en success

```
$.ajax({

    data: parametros,
    url: '../gestionUsuario/insertUsuario.php',
    type: 'post',

    success: function(response) {
        alert("hola success");
        if (response == 1) {
            alert("insertado");
            //$('#success_message').html('<h3>USUARIOS INSERTADO</h3>');
        } else {
            alert("no insertado");
            //$('#success_message').html('<h3>ERROS INSERCCION</h3>');
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("estatus " + xhr.status);
        alert("estatus " + xhr.responseText);
        alert("error " + thrownError)
    }
```

La ruta esta bien puesto que el php me inserta en la base de datos pero la respuesta entra en `error` y el `status` muestra 0.

Comment: Verificaste que tu archivo php no esta arrojando alguna excepcione ?

Comment: esto devuelve mi archivo php                                                                     if (mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
    el php funciona porque me inserta el registro en la base de datos

Comment: El hecho de que te inserte no significa que el PHP funcione **del todo**. ¿qué tal si da un error después de insertar? El `status 0` indica que el PHP no terminó de una forma satisfactoria. Es más, te puede dar un status 0 hasta en un archivo sin errores de sintaxis por ejemplo, pero que entra en un bucle demasiado largo que provoca un error del tipo timeout. Cosas como esas pueden ocurrir muchas, por lo que deberías revisar tu PHP.

Comment: @aitorlv la respuesta la tenés que imprimir en PHP. Cambiá el return por echo

Comment: @Mariano aún así, si la llamada Ajax está entrando en el bloque `error` es porque efectivamente algún error está ocurriendo del lado del servidor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te recomiendo revisar lo que esta retornando el código de PHP, en el caso del ejemplo he probado creando un archivo php con el contenido 1 y funciona correctamente, también lo probé con 0 y trabaja bien en mi localhost.

te recomiendo usar console.log(response) con el fin de averiguar lo que php esta retornando

```
var parametros = {
                "id" : 1,
                "nombre" : "Manuel",
        };
$.ajax({

    data: parametros,
    url: 'insertUsuario.php',
    type: 'post',
    beforeSend: function () {
                    console.log('Se inicia la petición');
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        alert("hola success");
        if (response == 1) {
            alert("insertado");
            //$('#success_message').html('<h3>USUARIOS INSERTADO</h3>');
            }else{
            alert("no insertado");
            //$('#success_message').html('<h3>ERROS INSERCCION</h3>');
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("estatus " + xhr.status);
        alert("estatus " + xhr.responseText);
        alert("error " + thrownError);
    }   
});
```

la respuesta se debe hacer con print o echo ya que javascript lo que lee es el texto plano generado, en el comentario anterior muestra una forma de averiguar si la consulta se hizo correctamente con affected_rows

```
if (mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0) { return 1; } else { return 0; }
```

Sin embargo para una petición ajax es recomendale hacer lo siguiente

```
if (mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0) { echo 1; } else { echo 0; }
```